# Parsing html table exception

Tags: c#, jquery, html-agility-pack

I am getting the below error while parsing html table with c#

> "An exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in
>   App_Web_k1wz0vym.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of an
>   object."
>
> at line  " foreach (HtmlNode row in table.SelectNodes("tr"))"

Below is my code

```
HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();

string s = requestsTable.InnerHtml.ToString();
doc.LoadHtml(s);

foreach (HtmlNode table in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("table"))
{
    foreach (HtmlNode row in table.SelectNodes("tr"))
    {
        ///This is the row.
        foreach (HtmlNode cell in row.SelectNodes("th|td"))
        {
            Response.Write("<br>"+cell.InnerText);
        }
    }
 }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: This is usually quite easy to debug. Check on this line, what object is "null". I would expect "table" to be null or table.SelectNodes() to be null. Then you can find out WHY it is null.

Comment: Seems that you cant find <table>'s in document root node, or some table is empty without rows.

Comment: But Table is loaded. error occurred during parsing the row.

Comment: @Chaitanya try to use debugger, debug the foreach method, find out what row is null